# Imprimindo arquivo texto em impressora termica com PrintDocument?

Tags: c#, winforms

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema em WinForms com C# e agora preciso gerar um cupom de recibo da venda e imprimir em uma impressora termica. Andei lendo sobre o PrintDocument mas não encontro exemplos de como gerar cupom usando esta API de impressão. Não sei qual é a configuração de impressão para bobinas como tamanho do papel, centralizar o texto, etc. Estou a procura de algum exemplo de como gerar isso. Como fazer isso ?

Estou tentando assim.

```
private PrintDocument printDocument = new PrintDocument();
private static String COMPROVANTE = Environment.CurrentDirectory + @"\comprovantes\comprovante.txt";
private String stringToPrint = "";

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            geraComprovante();
            imprimeComprovante();
        }

private void geraComprovante() {            
            FileStream fs = new FileStream(COMPROVANTE, FileMode.Create);
            StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(fs);
            writer.WriteLine("==========================================");
            writer.WriteLine("          NOME DA EMPRESA AQUI            ");
            writer.WriteLine("==========================================");
            writer.Close();
            fs.Close();
        }

        private void imprimeComprovante() {            
            FileStream fs = new FileStream(COMPROVANTE, FileMode.Open);
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fs);
            stringToPrint = sr.ReadToEnd();
            printDocument.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = DefaultPrinter.GetDefaultPrinterName();            
            printDocument.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler(printPage);
            printDocument.Print();
            sr.Close();
            fs.Close();
        }

        private void printPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e) {
            int charactersOnPage = 0;
            int linesPerPage = 0;
            Graphics graphics = e.Graphics;

            // Sets the value of charactersOnPage to the number of characters 
            // of stringToPrint that will fit within the bounds of the page.
            graphics.MeasureString(stringToPrint, this.Font,
                e.MarginBounds.Size, StringFormat.GenericTypographic,
                out charactersOnPage, out linesPerPage);

            // Draws the string within the bounds of the page
            graphics.DrawString(stringToPrint, this.Font, Brushes.Black,
                e.MarginBounds, StringFormat.GenericTypographic);

            // Remove the portion of the string that has been printed.
            stringToPrint = stringToPrint.Substring(charactersOnPage);

            // Check to see if more pages are to be printed.
            e.HasMorePages = (stringToPrint.Length > 0);
        }
```

Comment: Não tenho a resposta completa, mas uma dica: você pode utilizar o "StringFormat" no ultimo parametro de "graphics.DrawString" para centralizar o texto através das propriedades Alignment e LineAligment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Resolvido. Criei uma classe que estende `PrintDocument` e criei o comprovante conforme minha necessidade. Nem precisei gerar arquivo texto, fiz apenas usando o `Graphics` do `PrintDocument` msm. Funciona 100%.

fiz assim.

```
using System.Drawing.Printing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using TerminalControleDeVendas.domain;
using TerminalControleDeVendas.dao;


namespace TerminalControleDeVendas.utils {


    public class ImprimeVendaVista : PrintDocument{
        private Empresa empresa = new EmpresaDAO().getEmpresa();
        private Venda venda;        
        private Font bold = new Font(FontFamily.GenericSansSerif, 10, FontStyle.Bold);
        private Font regular = new Font(FontFamily.GenericSansSerif, 8, FontStyle.Regular);
        private Font regularItens = new Font(FontFamily.GenericSansSerif, 6,FontStyle.Regular);

        public ImprimeVendaVista(Venda venda){
            this.venda = venda;
            this.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = DefaultPrinter.GetDefaultPrinterName();
            this.OriginAtMargins = false;
            this.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler(printPage);
        }

        private void printPage(object send, PrintPageEventArgs e) {
            Graphics graphics = e.Graphics;
            int offset = 105;

            //print header
            graphics.DrawString(empresa.razaoSocial, bold, Brushes.Black, 20, 0);            
            graphics.DrawString(empresa.endereco.endereco + " Nº " + empresa.endereco.numero, regular, Brushes.Black, 100, 15);
            graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Black, 20, 30, 310, 30);
            graphics.DrawString("CUPOM NÃO FISCAL", bold, Brushes.Black, 80, 35);
            graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Black, 20, 50, 310, 50);
            graphics.DrawString("PEDIDO: " + FormatId.formatLong(venda.id), regular, Brushes.Black, 20, 60);            
            graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Black, 20, 75, 310, 75);

            //itens header
            graphics.DrawString("PRODUTO", regular, Brushes.Black, 20, 80);
            graphics.DrawString("UNIT.", regular, Brushes.Black, 150, 80);
            graphics.DrawString("QTD.", regular, Brushes.Black, 200, 80);
            graphics.DrawString("TOTAL", regular, Brushes.Black, 245, 80);
            graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Black, 20, 95, 310, 95);

            //itens de venda
            foreach(ItemVenda iv in venda.items){
                string produto = iv.produto.descricao;                
                graphics.DrawString(produto.Length > 20 ? produto.Substring(0,20) + "..." : produto, regularItens, Brushes.Black, 20, offset);
                graphics.DrawString(FormataMonetario.format(iv.valorUn), regularItens, Brushes.Black, 155, offset);
                graphics.DrawString(Convert.ToString(iv.quantidade), regularItens, Brushes.Black, 215, offset);
                graphics.DrawString(FormataMonetario.format(iv.total), regularItens, Brushes.Black, 250, offset);
                offset += 20;
            }
            //total
            graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Black, 20, offset, 310, offset);
            offset += 5;

            decimal total = 0;
            foreach (ItemVenda iv in venda.items) {
                total += iv.total;
            }
            graphics.DrawString("TOTAL R$: ", bold, Brushes.Black, 20, offset);
            graphics.DrawString(FormataMonetario.format(total), bold, Brushes.Black, 230, offset);
            offset += 15;

            graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Black, 20, offset, 310, offset);
            offset += 5;

            //bottom
            graphics.DrawString("Data: " + DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"), regularItens, Brushes.Black, 20, offset);
            graphics.DrawString("HORA: " + DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss"), regularItens, Brushes.Black, 220, offset);

            e.HasMorePages = false;

        }


    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Amigo, se eu entendi bem, vc quer imprimir em uma impressora não fiscal né? Pois bem, para isso você tem que integrar o respectivo modelo da impressora térmica que será usada, por exemplo, se eu for usar uma impressora Daruma, o próprio site da fabricante disponibiliza uma **dll** para os desenvolvedores, na própria dll ja tem todas as funções de impressão, conexão com o equipamento e etc. Tente dar uma olhada...

Comment: nao eh impressora fiscal nao, eh apenas termica. obrigado

Comment: Justo! Essa impressora que citei é **não fiscal**, segue uma imagem e me diz se ela é como esta:

https://http2.mlstatic.com/S_152221-MLB20746415003_052016-Y.jpg

Answer (score -1):

Eu definir 
       this.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = PrinterSettings.PrinterName; ;

Porque ele já estende de PrintDocument da classe Base.